# sudo as user within a python program

Tags: python-3.x, unix

I am trying to sudo as another user which is generic account in shell , however userid is still same after  su , any idea on how to fix it ?

```
import os,glob,pwd,subprocess,pexpect,getpass
print(getpass.getuser())
try:
    var_command = "su user"
    var_child = pexpect.spawn(var_command)
    i = var_child.expect(["Password:", pexpect.EOF])
    if i==0: # send password            
        print('Login SusccessFul' )    
        var_child.sendline("password")
        var_child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
    elif i==1:
        print("Got the key or connection timeout")
        pass
except Exception as e:
    print("Oops Something went wrong buddy")
    print(e)
print(getpass.getuser())
```

Comment: Your child process executing 'sudo' won't haver any effect on your original, parent process.

Comment: any suggestions on how to get it to work? in current shell